# Calling a virtual method in another class in the future

Tags: c++

I have an interface and something we can call "Server"

```
class MsgHandler {
 public:
  virtual void handleMsg1(int x) = 0;
  virtual void handleMsg2(int x) = 0;
  virtual void handleMsg3(int x) = 0;
};

class Server {
 public:
  void setMsgHandler(MsgHandler *h) { currentHandler = h; }
  MsgHandler* getMsgHandler() { return currentHandler; }
 private:
  MsgHandler *currentHandler;
};
```

and a class HandlerA:

```
class HandlerA : public MsgHandler {
 public:
   HandlerA(Server& s) : server(s) {}
   void handleMsg1(int x) override { /* do something */ }
   void handleMsg2(int x) override { 
     // do something more
     server.setMsgHandler(new HandlerB(s)); // Note that we change Handler here!
   }
   void handleMsg3(int x) override; // I'll come back to this below
 private:
   Server &server;
};
```

and a HandlerB:

```
class HandlerB : public MsgHandler {
 public:
   HandlerB(Server& s) : server(s) {}
   void handleMsg1(int x) override { /* do nothing */ }
   void handleMsg2(int x) override { /* do nothing */ }
   void handleMsg3(int x) override { /* do something really complex here */ }
 private:
   Server &server;
};
```

Now, let's assume I have an application which does something like this

```
Server s;
s.setMsgHandler(new HandlerA(s));
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg1(0); // Handled by HandlerA
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg2(43); // Handled by HandlerA
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg3(99); // Handled by HandlerB
```

So far so good. However, Let's assume that my application is anynchronous/non-deterministic, so that we sometimes might get this sequence instead:

```
Server s;
s.setNextMsgHandler(new HandlerA(s));
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg1(0);
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg3(99); // msg3 comes before msg2!!
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg2(43);
```

What I would like to do in HandlerA is something like this:

```
void HandlerA::handleMsg3(int x) {
  putMsgInQueue(MsgHandler::handleMsg3, x); // pseudo code!
}
```

and then I could go through the queue and maybe do something like this

```
s.setNextMsgHandler(new HandlerA(s));
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg1(0);
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg3(99); // msg3 comes before msg2, no problem
s.getMsgHandler()->handleMsg2(43);
processMsgFromQueue(s.getMsgHandler(), ...);
```

This queuing would simplify my code, becuase handleMsg3() might be very complex, and might also require information which I get in handleMsg2().

My question is: **How can I implement putMsgInQueue(...) / processMsgFromQueue(), or something similar?** I think I'm asking for a way to save a reference to a virtual method in a base class. Later when I want to invoke that method, invoking it will actually result in a call to the child class.

Please also consider the following before giving a too simple / too complex answer :-)

- The solution needs to be generic, i.e. I want to queue any handleMsgX(...)
- We can assume all the handleMsgX() methods in MsgHandler look the same, i.e. they all return void and they all have the same arguments
- Remember that at the time putMsgInQueue() is called, there exists no HandlerB instance. It is created later!

Comment: Looks like `std::queue<std::pair<void (MsgHandler::*)(int), int>>` should do the trick.